# Kafka compression fail in comsumer side

Tags: apache-kafka, compression, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have enabled snappy compression on the producer side with the following change:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG,"snappy");
```

Now if any change is required on consumer side for this? I checked the Consumer.config but did not find any compression_type parameter there.

And When I ran that code messages are not coming to consumer side and I am getting the following error:

```
[1/10/20 17:25:39:759 UTC] 00018027 org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer              I [Consumer clientId=com.ora.def.lieo, groupId=group-cedm] Seeking to offset 320 for partition Party-Resolved-Check-0
[1/10/20 17:25:49:760 UTC] 00018029 com.ibm.cedm.kafka.KafkaConsumerService                      E Received exception when fetching the next record from Party-Resolved-Check-0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no decompression config required. Consumers automatically handle this.

It's not clear how your error is related to compression

Comment: I think snappy jar is required at the consumer side which I was missing.

Comment: It is, but that comes as part of kafka-clients dependency

Comment: No idea about that, but it got resolved by adding the jar file.